# Opera - webApp slides up when button pressed

Tags: web-applications, button, mootools, opera

I am developing this web application and I have came across a "little" problem in Opera 11.01 browser. When I press any `<button>` on the app, the page slides up.

To reproduce (the system is in Polish, so follow the steps):

1. Go to https://postplus.pl/demo .
2. Press "Zaloguj" (the button with green tick icon).
3. When logged in, press the button "Nowa" (or any other button on the left panel).

What is happening?

Comment: I don't know why...but the app looks nice!

Comment: good old mochaui. :) do you really want to worry about an old version of opera? in any case, check your event binding code around the buttons, make sure you stop the events properly (old mochaui used to `new Event(e).stop()` although I am not sure this applies here as you seem to have an action element property that defines the callback - where you don't seem to touch the event). Perhaps you should...

Comment: "good old mochaui"? Is the new (still in development) MochaUI worse or something? I'm asking because I'm waiting for the new version to port my project. And you've got me a little worried. :) PS. This opera version is last stable release.

Comment: Maybe someone knows a patch to this? I have to fix it because 12% of my visitors have Opera 11.01 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced all the <button> tags with <a> tag (with proper styling). It is only solution that came to my mind.

Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much.. works fine for me in Opera 11.10

Answer (score 1):

This is an Opera bug (for some reason thinks the element is off-screen and must be scrolled into view or something). A fix is implemented so I suggest you simply try to ignore this issue. While Opera users upgrade, fewer and fewer of them will be affected by the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry to take back the acceptance but I have to fix it. Even a patch especially for this version of Opera would be OK.